# Angular directive: using ng-model within isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having trouble working out how I can define a custom directive that both:

1. Uses isolate scope, and
2. Uses the ng-model directive in a new scope within in its template.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <dir model="foo.bar"></dir>
    Outside directive: {{foo.bar}}
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.foo = { bar: 'baz' };
  })
  .directive('dir', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        model: '='
      },
      template: '<div ng-if="true"><input type="text" ng-model="model" /><br/></div>'
    }
  });
```

The desired behaviour here is that the input's value is bound to the outer scope's `foo.bar` property, via the the directive's (isolate) scope `model` property. That doesn't happen, because the ng-if directive on the template's enclosing div creates a new scope, so it's that scope's `model` that gets updated, not the directive's scope's.
Ordinarily you solve these ng-model issues by making sure there's a dot in the expression, but I can't see any way to do that here. I wondered if I might be able to use something like this for my directive:

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    model: {
      value: '=model'
    }
  },
  template: '<div ng-if="true"><input type="text" ng-model="model.value" /><br/></div>'
}
```

but that doesn't work...

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/usxZ9aonMUenMDtSXre4?p=preview)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right - ng-if creates a child scope which is causing a problem when text is entered in the input text field. It creates a shadow property named 'model' in child scope which is a copy of the parent scope variable with the same name - effectively breaking the two-way model binding.

The fix for this is simple. In your template, specify the $parent prefix:

```
  template: '<div ng-if="true">
                   <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.model" /><br/>
             </div>'
```

This ensures that it will resolve 'model' from the $parent scope, which you've already setup for two-way model binding through the isolated scope.

In the end, the '.' in ng-model saves the day. I find it useful to think about anything left of the dot as a way for Angular to resolve the property through scope inheritance.  Without the dot, resolving the property only becomes an issue when we're assigning scope variables (otherwise, lookups are fine, including read-only `{{model}}` binding expressions).

Comment: Thanks - I'd totally forgotten about $parent. This does solve my issue in this case, but I'm still a bit hesitant about it as a general purpose solution: it means I have to keep track of where new scopes are introduced in my templates and what level of the hierarchy I need to target, which seems pretty error-prone...

Comment: I agree with you. Misko explained that someone logs a bug about this about once a week - its not really a bug, its the way prototypical inheritance works. To set ng-model correctly, you need to know how scope inheritance works at a deeper level, and also which directives will create child scopes.  I can't think of a better way though.

Comment: Yeah, fair point, though I guess what I was getting at is that there's a particular problem with using ng-model="$parent.bar" as opposed to ng-model="foo.bar", in that with the former I always have to think about where child scopes are being created, whereas with the latter I don't (so long as I can assume that no child scopes have a property called 'foo').

Comment: Re. update: thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that works - when using this method changing the input's value updates $scope.foo.bar, but there's no two-way binding between $scope.foo.bar and the model property passed into the directive from the outer controller, so that outer property does not update. See http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZnUEbJHybq3765PxgoY?p=preview (I had to tweak your example slightly, but I think it reflects your idea).

Comment: In your example "foo" is resolving to different references. Bar is a primitive. That is what's breaking the two-way binding. You should pass foo as the model, and all these issues go away.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` creates an additional prototypally inheriting scope, so `ng-model="model"` binds to the inherited property of the new scope and not to the 2-way binded property of the directive scope.

Change it to `ng-show` and it will [work](http://plnkr.co/edit/CE8mStZ6f75bf5nqtLWG?p=preview).

You can use [a small Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) i've written to inspect angular scopes.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that that's what's happening - I used ng-if on purpose just to demonstrate the issue