# How to support ng-model in my custom input (angular directive)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on the angular directive which is a form input kind of widget. The user picks the values using this input and I want the result to be available in ng-model, something like that:

```
<mydirective ng-model="mod">
</mydirective>
```

I heard that it got a lot easier in the new versions of Angular 1.

**UPD** I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537960) but I think that the way that has been proposed is too much of an overengineering. Posted the short answer to my own question that utilises only the `link` function.

Comment: what did you want to do ? to isolate the scope of the directive ou share the scope of the parent ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26538540/4747123. Great answer to the same question with tons of detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding ngModel to a custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537960/binding-ngmodel-to-a-custom-directive)

Comment: he was talking about the his problems in such great details that I lost my patience and figured the acceptable answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got one way to do it. Suppose we need a directive that consists of one input and one dropdown. I want to use it as form input with ng-model. The concatenated result is going to be put to ng-model.

My solution is that in my directive I have a bunch of ng-models which I watch with the scope.$watch. Every time something is updated I update the ngModel parameter which I injected into scope. The code looks like this:

Directive:

```
angular.module('oneClickRegistration')
    .directive('awesomedir', function () {
        var tpl = "<div> \
        <input type='text' ng-model='model.num' size='80' /> \
        <select ng-model='model.unit'> \
            <option value='secs'>Seconds</option> \
            <option value='mins'>Minutes</option> \
            <option value='hours'>Hours</option> \
            <option value='days'>Days</option> \
        </select> \
    </div>";

        return {
            template: tpl,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.$watchGroup(['model.num','model.unit'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope){
                    scope.ngModel=newValues[0]+ " " + newValues[1];
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

And here how I use the directive:

```
    <awesomedir ng-model="record.dir_res"></awesomedir>
```